# Grid collapsing Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, e-commerce

made a grid of goods Bootstrap 3, all good, but when the name of the product does not fit on one line, the entire grid flies and get this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

A living example with code [here](http://dohms.ru/index.php?num=9)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding this code:

```
.col-md-4 {
   min-height: 390px !important;
}
```